# Change default Banana dashboard pointer

Tags: solr, configuration, banana

I want to change the default route to the Banana default dashboard.
Because I don’t want to load a file each time I launch Banana and if I want to use an other computer, I will be owned…

I don’t know where I can find this variable, in which file.

I saw this on the config.js file, but I don’t really understand :

```
The default Solr index to use for storing objects internal to Banana, such as 
stored dashboards. If you have been using a collection named kibana-int 
to save your dashboards (the default provided in Banana 1.2 and earlier), then you
simply need to replace the string "banana-int" with "kibana-int" and your old 
dashboards will be accessible. 
This banana-int (or equivalent) collection must be created and available in the 
default solr server specified above, which serves as the persistence store for data 
internal to banana.
```

Does someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution :).

It is in dashboards.js in the src/app/services directory. I had to change the lines marked default.json by the file exported from my Banana, putted in the src/app/dasboards directory.

And information is available at this address :  http://blog.trifork.com/2014/05/20/advanced-kibana-dashboard/ (it is Kibana, but Banana is a fork of Kibana).